# Advanced Custom Fields Plugin - Unable to get URL from post_object

Tags: custom-field

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have a field called "grid_thumbnail" and a "related_projects" post_object. I am able to display the title of the related post. I just don't know how to get the Image URL of that related post. Suggestions?

```
<?php foreach(get_field('related_projects') as $post_object): ?>

<li>
<img src="<?php echo get_field('grid_thumbnail'); ?>"><br />
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID) ?></a>
</li>
```

## Edit

print_r returns:

```
stdClass Object ( [ID] => 100 
[post_author] => 1 
[post_date] => 2012-01-12 05:11:25 
[post_date_gmt] => 2012-01-12 05:11:25 
[post_content] => Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque non tincidunt est. Nulla porta bibendum auctor. Proin feugiat eros bibendum lacus viverra fringilla ac id felis. Praesent a commodo leo. Phasellus et odio eget justo venenatis interdum at ut nulla. Praesent lacinia nulla eu libero tempus pulvinar. Sed elementum, nulla vitae imperdiet ornare, elit lorem vestibulum erat, ac aliquet purus lacus pharetra risus. Mauris facilisis volutpat odio a ultrices. Etiam nisl urna, mattis sed ultricies sit amet, euismod sit amet eros. Nam tempus erat ut ligula elementum cursus faucibus elit accumsan. Fusce rhoncus, nunc nec vestibulum facilisis, nibh leo vestibulum metus, vitae malesuada leo dui eu erat. Proin scelerisque, mi viverra dignissim porta, lectus justo pellentesque metus, at consequat ligula nulla eu ante. Fusce fringilla pretium venenatis. Quisque quis arcu porta dolor condimentum viverra at id augue. Donec pharetra venenatis felis. 
[post_title] => Rada 
[post_excerpt] => 
[post_status] => publish 
[comment_status] => open 
[ping_status] => open 
[post_password] => 
[post_name] => rada-2 
[to_ping] => 
[pinged] => 
[post_modified] => 2012-01-16 23:01:37 
[post_modified_gmt] => 2012-01-16 23:01:37 
[post_content_filtered] => 
[post_parent] => 0 
[guid] => http://estevancarlos.kodingen.com/ecv7/?post_type=projects&p=100 
[menu_order] => 0 
[post_type] => projects 
[post_mime_type] => 
[comment_count] => 0 
[ancestors] => Array ( ) [filter] => raw )
```

Comment: what does a `print_r( $post_object )` give you? I have a feeling that `$post_object` is not a post object...

Comment: You can take a look here: http://estevancarlos.kodingen.com/ecv7/?projects=pronto-sabre-quien-soy

Comment: I'm inclined to believe, based on that, that the issue is in your `get_field()`, either that or you're having a variable name conflict with `$post_object`. `get_field()` is not a wordpress core function, where is that function coming from?

Comment: I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.  It comes from that.

Comment: Why not use `$post_object->title`? Are you just looking for the filters? Also, is the permalink working and just the title's broken?

Comment: Why not? Because I don't understand those details.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this: <img src="<?php echo get_field($post_object->grid_thumb); ?>">  Get a thumbnail src from a related post.

Comment: AH, I see, I thought you were having an issue with get_the_title(), alright, what does a print_r( get_field( 'grid_thumbnail' ) ) yield?

Comment: You can view it here: http://estevancarlos.kodingen.com/ecv7/?projects=rada-2. 

Basically it pulls the Url of the "grid_thumb" for the current post.  However I'm trying to get the URL for 'grid_thumb' for the 'related_projects' field.  I'm not sure how to retrieve meta data from an outside post using this plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a second parameter on `get_field()` which you are not using, try this line instead:

`<img src="<?php echo get_field( 'grid_thumbnail', $post_object->ID ); ?>"><br />`

Docs: [`get_field()`](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/documentation/get_field/)

Answer (score 1):

Use **addslashes** in PHP.

As described in [this page](http://blog.linz.im/2012/acf-image-url.html) (in chinese), this would work:

```
$main_car_pic = addslashes(get_field('car_photo'));
$reg_ext = "#.jpg#i";
$thumb_ext = "-150x150.jpg";
$car_thumb = preg_replace($reg_ext, $thumb_ext, $main_car_pic);

echo $car_thumb
```

Or simply like this:

```
<?php echo addslashes(get_field('field_name')); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Quasimo, welcome to WordPress StackExchange! . . Note that only a link to an external site is not considered a good Answer. . . . Please take a moment to read this [Stack FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) to better understand its mechanics.